# Continue Executing PHP after Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this block of HTML:

```
<div class="box-body" id="mcontent">
           <?php
                if (isset($_POST["id"])){
                    $id = $_POST["id"];
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select complain from tbcomplains where cid = '$id';");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        echo $row["complain"];
                    }

                }

             }
             echo "<br /> <p />";
             echo "<p> Copy this link and paste in the mail for user's responses <br />";
             echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
           ?>
        </div>
```

Which is replaced with this Ajax call, I include the the script below:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
       var rex = e.target.id;  //$('#this').data('id');
       $('#mcontent').load("doload.php", {id:$('#' + rex ).data("id")}); 
   });
```

The above code works perfectly.  Issue is, how do I force this part of HTML to execute after the Jquery has finished.

I want this part of the PHP/HTML to execute:

```
echo "<br /> <p />";
                 echo "<p> Copy this link and paste in the mail for user's responses <br />";
                 echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: You're not using Ajax. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is one of the jQuery shorthand AJAX methods @executable

Comment: You have to use another AJAX call to execute something on the server. Or do you want to redirect?

Comment: what's in `doload.php`?

Comment: Thanks for you responses.

Content of interst in doload.php
`if ($result = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)){
    if ($result= mysqli_store_result($con)){
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row["complain"];
        }
    }
}
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the fact that Javascript is a client-side language, you won't be able to "force" PHP to wait for an AJAX response.

The only possibility to modify your existing DOM after the AJAX call would be to use javascript when the query has responded.